# Once again: typescript function overload

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Usually I can master most of typescript language's features, but function overloading sometimes is still quite challenging.

I can't get my head around to why typescript compiler keeps throwing `error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation` on the following code (mcve):

```
class Editor {
  replace(
    searchValue: { [Symbol.match](string: string): RegExpMatchArray; }, 
    replaceValue: string,
  ): this;

  replace(
    searchValue: { [Symbol.match](string: string): RegExpMatchArray; },
    replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string,
  ): this {
    return this;
  }
}
```

The only difference lies on the 2nd argument: either `string` or `(substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string`.

Why can't the compiler just mend them together as `string | (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last signature is the implementation signature and must be compatible with **all** overloads. In this case `Editor` defines just one public signature, the one with `string` and the implementation signature is the one with the callback. This was probably not your intention, you probably wanted both signatures to be available:

```
class Editor {
    replace(
        searchValue: { [Symbol.match](string: string): RegExpMatchArray; }, 
        replaceValue: string,
    ): this;
    replace(
        searchValue: { [Symbol.match](string: string): RegExpMatchArray; },
        replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string,
    ): this
    replace(
        searchValue: { [Symbol.match](string: string): RegExpMatchArray; },
        replacer: string | ((substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string),
    ): this {
    return this;
    }
}
```

As to why the compiler can't just stich together the implementation signature, overload vs implementation signature difference can get pretty big (with the implementation signature sometimes just using `any` for everything), It was probably considered best to allow the developer to choose the implementation signature with a minimal compatibility check to prevent accidental mistakes.